# SQL Update a table based on join with anther table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, ora-00933

I am trying to update a table by joining the values with another table.
Here's my query so far.

```
    UPDATE LOGIN  SET LOGIN.DISABLED_IND = 'N', LOGIN.DREASON = 'Test'
        FROM  CONTACT
        WHERE CONTACT.CONTACT_ID = LOGIN.CONTACT_ID 
        AND CONTACT.RID ='abc'
```

When i run this, i get this

```
[Error Code: 933, SQL State: 42000] ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you expect to update a large fraction of the rows in `LOGIN`, it will likely be more efficient to use an EXISTS

```
UPDATE LOGIN  l
   SET l.DISABLED_IND = 'N', 
       l.DREASON = 'Test'
 WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
      FROM CONTACT c
     WHERE c.CONTACT_ID = l.CONTACT_ID 
       AND c.RID ='abc' )
```

If you are updating a relatively small fraction of the rows in `LOGIN`, Yahia's approach of using an IN would likely be more efficient

```
UPDATE LOGIN  l
   SET l.DISABLED_IND = 'N', 
       l.DREASON = 'Test'
 WHERE l.contact_id IN (
    SELECT c.contact_id
      FROM CONTACT c
     WHERE c.RID ='abc' )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and time, really appreciate it. Your answer was by far great and more detail and you raised excellent point of caring updating for large dataset. Let me try it and get back to you. Thanks again :).

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thanks a lot for your time, lastly can you please suggest resources (book, articles) for mastering sql from beginner level to expert level. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

try

```
 UPDATE LOGIN L SET L.DISABLED_IND = 'N', L.DREASON = 'Test'
 WHERE L.CONTACT_ID 
 IN ( SELECT C.CONTACT_ID FROM CONTACT C WHERE C.CONTACT_ID = L.CONTACT_ID AND 
 C.RID='abc');
```

Another more complicated option see http://geekswithblogs.net/WillSmith/archive/2008/06/18/oracle-update-with-join-again.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is not quite correct. This [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Update_%28SQL%29) has number of examples that you can choose from.

For example

```
UPDATE l
 SET l.DISABLED_IND = 'N', l.DREASON = 'Test'
 FROM LOGIN l
  JOIN CONTACT c
   ON c.CONTACT_ID = l.CONTACT_ID AND c.RID ='abc'
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried it i am getting this error.
[Error Code: 933, SQL State: 42000]  ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: Not all of the examples in that article will work on Oracle.  And even the Oracle specific version didn't work until I fixed it a few months ago.  That article is a good example of why Wikipedia is not a good resource for programming.